# Increase height of cell without configuring it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I have so `UITableView` in that i have custom cell.That custom cell contains some labels .The text of label can be dynamic depending upon the Json. Now i want to make the height of cell based on the content height of the label so i have used the method `heightForRowAtINdexPath`.Now i am getting the cell like this.

```
if(!self.customCell)
    {
        self.customCell = [self.table_view dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeCell"];
    }
```

the labels can be multiline depending upon the data.So i if write the same code of `cellForRowAtiNdexPath` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` then i get more height.but if i don't write the same code then i get less height for labels.
as of now i have written below code for `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
-   (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height;
      float like_height,c_one_height,c_two_height,c_three_height,tv_height,header_height,operations_height,img_like_icon_height,img_comment_icon_height,header_margin=5,tv_container_margin=5,operations_margin=5,like_top_margin=11,first_comment=10,second_comment=5,third_comment=5;
    //define variables here
    if(!self.customCell)
    {
        self.customCell = [self.table_view dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeCell"];
    }
    Post *user_post=[arr_post objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    int like_count=[user_post.like_count intValue];
    float comment_count=[user_post.comment_count intValue];
    if (self.customCell.beizer_image != nil)

    {
        NSLog(@"inside cell beizer");

        [self.customCell.beizer_image removeFromSuperview];

        self.customCell.beizer_image=nil;

        self.customCell.tv_post.textContainer.exclusionPaths=NULL;

        self.customCell.beizer_path=nil;

    }
    [self.customCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    self.customCell.tv_post.text=user_post.post_description;
    self.customCell.tv_post.font = [UIFont fontWithName:user_post.font_family size:[user_post.font_size floatValue]];
    [self.customCell.tv_post setTextColor:[self colorFromHexString:user_post.font_color]];
    if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
    {

        NSLog(@"NOT INSIDE THE CONDITION");

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"INSIDE BEIZER PATH CONDITION");
        self.customCell.beizer_path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 100)];
        self.customCell.tv_post.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[self.customCell.beizer_path];
        self.customCell.beizer_image =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 100)];

        if(![user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {
            [self.customCell.beizer_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_image]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

        }
        if(![user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
        {
            [self.customCell.beizer_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_video_thumbnail]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];

        }
        [self.customCell.tv_post addSubview:self.customCell.beizer_image];
    }
    //make textview height dynamic
    self.customCell.tv_post.scrollEnabled=NO;
    if([user_post.post_image isEqualToString:@"none"] && [user_post.post_video isEqualToString:@"none"])
    {
        CGFloat fixedWidth = self.customCell.tv_post.frame.size.width;
        CGSize newSize = [self.customCell.tv_post sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
        CGRect newFrame = self.customCell.tv_post.frame;
        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
        self.customCell.tv_post.frame = newFrame;
        self.customCell.tv_height.constant=self.customCell.tv_post.frame.size.height;
        [self.customCell.view_tvContainer layoutIfNeeded];
    }
    else
    {
        CGFloat fixedWidth = self.customCell.tv_post.frame.size.width;
        CGSize newSize = [self.customCell.tv_post sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
        CGRect newFrame = self.customCell.tv_post.frame;
        newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth),fmax(self.customCell.beizer_image.frame.size.height+10,newSize.height));
        self.customCell.tv_post.frame = newFrame;
        self.customCell.tv_height.constant=self.customCell.tv_post.frame.size.height;
        [self.customCell.view_tvContainer layoutIfNeeded];
    }

//    self.customCell.f_comment_top.constant=-2100;
//    [self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];
    if(like_count>0)
    {
        like_height=self.customCell.label_like_count.frame.size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        like_height=0;
        img_like_icon_height=0;
    }
    if(comment_count<=0)
    {
        c_one_height=0;
        c_two_height=0;
        c_three_height=0;
        img_comment_icon_height=0;
    }
    else if(comment_count==1)
    {

        if(like_count<=0)
        {
            self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            self.customCell.f_comment_top.constant=-21;
            [self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];
        }
        c_one_height=self.customCell.first_comment.frame.size.height;
        c_two_height=0;
        c_three_height=0;

    }
    else if(comment_count==2)
    {
        if(like_count<=0)
        {
            self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            self.customCell.f_comment_top.constant=-21;
            [self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];
        }
        c_one_height=self.customCell.first_comment.frame.size.height;
        c_two_height=self.customCell.second_cmment.frame.size.height+15;
        c_three_height=0;
    }
    else if(comment_count==3)
    {
        if(like_count<=0)
        {
//            self.customCell.f_comment_top.constant=1020;
//            [self.customCell.first_comment layoutIfNeeded];
        }
        else
        {

        }
        c_one_height=self.customCell.first_comment.frame.size.height;
        c_two_height=self.customCell.second_cmment.frame.size.height;
        c_three_height=self.customCell.third_comment.frame.size.height+15;
    }
    tv_height=self.customCell.view_tvContainer.frame.size.height;
    header_height=self.customCell.header_view_height.frame.size.height;
    operations_height=self.customCell.view_operations_height.frame.size.height;
    height = like_height+c_one_height+c_two_height+c_three_height+tv_height+operations_height+header_height;
    CGFloat margin_height=header_margin+operations_margin+tv_container_margin+like_top_margin+first_comment+second_comment+third_comment+img_comment_icon_height+img_like_icon_height;
    NSLog(@"like label height is %f",like_height);
    NSLog(@"first comment height is %f",c_one_height);
    NSLog(@"second comment height is %f",c_two_height);
    NSLog(@"third comment height is %f",c_three_height);
    NSLog(@"all margin  height is %f",margin_height);
    NSLog(@"height is %f",height);

    // Padding of 1 point (cell separator)
    height=height+margin_height;
    CGFloat separatorHeight = 1;
    return height;

}
```

I have seen many example in which it is written that for configuring cell the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is written in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

1. Why i need to repeat the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in
   `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

**Why i need to repeat the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath in heightForRowAtIndexPath?**

> > because heightForRowAtIndexPath will always get called before cellForRowAtIndexPath. So to calculate height in heightForRowAtIndexPath you have create that cell in heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Best way to use autolayout for dynamic height calculation:- 
You can refer following [Link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) to do the same.

Comment: That will be time consuming process as well it decrease performance.

Comment: no .... autolayout will work like charm ..... you should try it if you know how to use autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to configure the `entire` cell which you have declared in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

These are two methods used for specific functionality.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a `DataSource` method which is meant for configuring your cell in `tableview`.

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is a `Delegate` method which is meant to calculate the height of the `tableviewcell` or `row` based on the content which you are planning to show in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

For example, if you are configuring a cell with a `UILabel` (no matter how many labels) and assign the label with some text in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, then in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, fetch the text that you have assigned to label, calcluate label's height and give this height of the label to the cell. This will create the cell which have height according to your label's height.

For example, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`,

```
        .....//your cell configuration code above//.....
        UILabel *lbl_myText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [lbl_myText setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        lbl_myText.minimumScaleFactor = FONT_SIZE;
        [lbl_myText setNumberOfLines:0];
        lbl_myText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        [lbl_myText setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];

        NSString *text = [arr_text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(Your_MAX_LabelWidth, Your_MAX_LabelHeight);


        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];

        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;


        CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle.copy}
                                                 context:nil];

         size = textRect.size;


         [lbl_myText setText:text];
         float widthIs = [lbl_myText.text
             boundingRectWithSize:constraint
             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
             attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:lbl_myText.font }
             context:nil]
            .size.width;
         [lbl_myText setFrame:CGRectMake(X_co,Y_co,widthIs,size.height)];
```

in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    .....//NO cell configuration code above//.....
    NSString *cellText = [arr_text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(Your_MAX_LabelWidth, Your_MAX_LabelHeight);

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];

    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    ////for message label
    CGRect textRect = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle.copy}
                                             context:nil];

    CGSize labelsize = textRect.size;



    ///calculate Cell the height
    CGFloat height = MAX(labelsize.height, your_defaultcell_height);

    if(height == your_defaultcell_height)
    {
       return your_defaultcell_height + 10; //10 is buffer height
    }

    else
    {
        return height + 10;  //10 is buffer height
    }
```